# Redux - Data Store - Don't understand this syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am studying React.js and I am on the Redux section.

There is this code, I don't understand why it is written like this. 
It is explaining the creation of the initial state of a data store. And it is explained that redux uses pure JavaScript.

**src/store/initialData.js**

```js
import { PRODUCTS, SUPPLIERS } from "./dataTypes";
export const initialData = {
    [PRODUCTS]: [
        { id: 1, name: "Trail Shoes", category: "Running", price: 100 },
        { id: 2, name: "Thermal Hat", category: "Running", price: 12 },
        { id: 3, name: "Heated Gloves", category: "Running", price: 82.50 }],
    [SUPPLIERS]: [
        { id: 1, name: "Zoom Shoes", city: "London", products: [1] },
        { id: 2, name: "Cosy Gear", city: "New York", products: [2, 3] }],
}
```

**src/store/dataTypes.js**

```js
export const PRODUCTS = "products";
export const SUPPLIERS = "suppliers";
```

My question is that why is there a syntax like this :

> [PRODUCT]: [...]

I just don't understand the square brackets around PRODUCT. 
I've never seen this syntax before when defining object. Can someone explain that syntax to me?

Comment: That syntax is used in order to be able to set a dynamic variable as the object's key. It's more of a stylistic preference that allows for the same variable to be referenced somewhere else in the code without having to worry if there will be any mis-matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a JavaScript/ECMAScript specific question. When you can assign a constant property name to an object pretty easily using the dot notation:

```
const initialData = {};
initialData.products = [...];
```

However, in that case `PRODUCTS` is a dynamic imported value. Therefore, you have to use the bracket notation to assign such a property:

```
import { PRODUCTS } from './dataTypes';

const initialData = {};
initialData[PRODUCTS] = [...];
```

You can also do something like:

```
const initialData = {};
initialData['pro' + 'ducts'] = [...];
```

Comment: Thanks very much, @Dmitry. Is there a name for this specific technique in the JavaScript/ECMAScript reference so I can read more on the subject.

Comment: Isn't that Object destructuring.

Comment: They just call it bracket notation on the Mozilla JavaScript reference page.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: @Sam Object destructuring is something different. Ex:

let a; let b;
({ a, b } = { a: 10, b: 20 });
console.log(a); // 10
console.log(b); // 20